# Express in partial fractions and expand the terms using binomial expansion up to $x^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

[image]$$
\frac{2}{(1-x)\left(1+x^{2}\right)}
$$

This is then split into partial fractions

$$
\frac{A}{1-x}+\frac{B x+C}{1+x^{2}}
$$

Computing this i had gotten

\begin{equation}
2=A\left(1+x^{2}\right)+(B x+C)(1-x)
\end{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
2=A+A x^{2}-B x-B x^{2}+C-C x \\
2=(A-B) x^{2}+(B-C) x+(B+C)
\end{array}
A-B=0
b-c=0
A+c=2
B=1 A=1 C=1
As my final answer for i)

\end{array}$$
\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{x+1}{1+x^{2}}
$$

ii) "Expand $$
\frac{1}{1-x}
$$ up to and including the term in \begin{equation}
x^{3}
\end{equation}

(1-x)^-1
=1+x+x^2+x^3.... as my final solution

iii), iv) and v) I am unsure where to go next, is it the same process for iii and iv again?

Edit:

iii) for my final answer I had gotten $$
\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}=\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{-1}=1-x^{2}+\left(x^{2}\right)^{2}-\left(x^{3}\right)^{3}
$$

iv) $$\frac{2}{(1-x)\left(1+x^{2}\right)}=\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{x+1}{1+x^{2}}
$$

simplfiyng

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\left(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+\ldots\right)+(x+1)\left(1-x^{2}+. .\right) \\
=1+x+x^{2}+x^{3} . .+x+x^{3}+1-x^{2} \ldots \\
=2+2 x+0 x^{2}+0 x^{3}
\end{array}
$$

v) x<1

vi) $$
\begin{array}{l}
(9+0.045)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
{\left[\left(1+\frac{0.045}{9}\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}=3(1+0.005)^{\frac{1}{2}}\right.}
\end{array}
$$ So far this is my process

Comment: To expand $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ you can either use that $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ (which contains the information of part (ii)) and replace $x$ with $-x^2$. Alternatively, you can do a couple of steps of polynomial long division of $1$ divided by $1+x^2$, in this order of the monomials. Part(iv) is solved by combining the results of part (ii) and (iii) according to the partial fraction decomposition from part (i).

Comment: I fail to notice any connection between questions (i)–(v) and question (vi).

Comment: Thank you I will demonstrate my workings on iii, iv and v

Comment: I think for v and vi whatever answer i get for v it will lead onto vi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iii), you can do $\frac{1}{1 + x^{2}}$ = $1 - x^{2} + x^{4}$...... This can be rewritten as $1 + 0x - x^{2} + 0x^{3} + x^{4}$......, though if this is a homework question, your teacher may or may not accept this.

For iv), you use the result in i)
$$\frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{x}{1 + x^{2}} + \frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$$

The first term can be written as $1 + x + x^{2} + x^{3}...$

The second term can be written as $x*(1 - x^2 + x^4....)$ = $x - x^3 + x^5...$

The third term is the answer for iii), $1 - x^2 + x^4...$

Now we have to combine these terms. For sake of brevity I'll let you do it. You would take care of each term modulus 4 .

For v), remember that our expansion is equal to
$$\frac{2}{(1 - x)(1+ x^2)}$$

So to find when our expansion  converges, we can find when the above is finite, i.e. when it doesn't equal infinity. It equals infinity when the denominator equals 0 -- asuming this is limited to real numbers, that would be when x = 1. So the expansion converges for $x \neq 1$